# xml c# add element with Linq to Xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i need some help in adding an element, right now i am doing this :

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(testFile);
xDoc.Descendants("SQUIBLIST")
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Add(new XElement("Sensor", 
            new XAttribute("ID", id + 1), 
            new XAttribute("Name", "Squib" + (id + 1).ToString()), 
            new XAttribute("Used", "True")));
xDoc.Save(testFile);
```

and i am getting ( for example ):

```
   <Sensor ID="26" Name="Squib26" Used="True" />
```

what i want is  this :

```
   <Sensor ID="26" Name="Squib26" Used="True"></Sensor>
```

and i can't find the way to do it. 
Pease give me a clue . Thanks!

Comment: Those are the same thing.  Why do you want the second one and not the first one?

Comment: Potential duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355147/how-do-you-force-explicit-tag-closing-with-linq-xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462747/explicit-element-closing-tags-with-system-xml-linq-namespace

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reformatting your code to use shorter lines - *certainly* on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include an empty string to force it to add an empty text node:

```
new XElement("Sensor", 
    new XAttribute("ID", id + 1), 
    new XAttribute("Name", "Squib" + (id + 1).ToString()),
    new XAttribute("Used", "True"),
    "")
```

However, you should consider why you really need this. Typically applications reading the XML simply shouldn't care about the difference.

Also note that by calling `FirstOrDefault().Add(...)` you'll fail with a `NullReferenceException` if there aren't any `SQUIBLIST` elements. It would *at least* be clearer to use `First()` so that *that* can fail if there are no such elements, rather than returning `null`.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon, that worked perfectly, and i have also reformatted my code as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 xDoc.Descendants("SQUIBLIST")
      .FirstOrDefault()
      .Add(
             new XElement("Sensor", 
             new XAttribute("ID", id + 1), 
             new XAttribute("Name", "Squib" + (id + 1).ToString()), 
             new XAttribute("Used", "True")
             ,"" //<-- this will represent the value of <Sensor>
));
```