# Check if XML element equals another XML element, ignoring empty values

Tags: c#, xml

I'm checking if two XML elements given by string are equal with this method:

```
private static bool XmlEquals(string s1, string s2)
{
    return XNode.DeepEquals(XElement.Parse(s1), XElement.Parse(s2));
}
```

This work unless one of the elements has opening and closing tags and the other has a closed tag like this:

```
<MyElement SomeAttribute="some value" />
<MyElement SomeAttribute="some value"></MyElement>
```

Can I somehow compare two XML elements in a way, that the above case is considered **equal**?

Comment: Have you try to compare them as string ?

Comment: I think you need to look for some tree implementation than traverse it checking nodes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This question seems to have similar if not equal issues of semantic differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318157/best-way-to-compare-xelement-objects

Comment: Do the attributes must have same values?

Comment: @CheapDiamond how should that work, the string don't even have the same length ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straightforward way to solve this particular problem is to [introduce closing brackets explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462747/explicit-element-closing-tags-with-system-xml-linq-namespace):

```
 private static bool XmlEquals(string s1, string s2)
 {
      var firstElement = XElement.Parse(s1);
      var secondElement = XElement.Parse(s2);
      IntroduceClosingBracket(firstElement);
      IntroduceClosingBracket(secondElement);

      return XNode.DeepEquals(firstElement, secondElement);
 }

 private static void IntroduceClosingBracket(XElement element)
 {
      foreach (var descendant in element.DescendantsAndSelf())
      {
           if (descendant.IsEmpty)
           {
                descendant.SetValue(String.Empty);
           }
      }
 }
```

Loop through all descendants may cause a performance hit, though.

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen so far, it works, but I had to add `if (element.IsEmpty) { element.SetValue(string.Empty); }` in the `IntroduceClosingBracket` method for it to work correctly.

Comment: @Hinek Oh, silly me, I wrote a test for nested elements from the start and didn't check the obvious case. I'll fix it, thank you!

Comment: Now it's beautiful. Thanks, you were a great help!

Comment: @Hinek You're welcome! You might want to check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318157/best-way-to-compare-xelement-objects) from J.Steen's comment. There're other issues with XML comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If the XMLs does not have to be perfectly identical like in @defaultlocale's solution which really compares everything (even comments) you could use `LINQ` to compare only things that you are interested in. To show the idea I've made the comparison of attribute values optional.

Test data:

```
var xml1 = @"
    <elm1 attr1='val1'>
        <elm2 attr2='val1'>
            <elm3 attr3='val1' />
        </elm2>
    </elm1>";

var xml2 = @"
    <elm1 attr1='val1'>
        <elm2 attr2='val1'>
            <elm3 attr3='val1' attr='val2' />
        </elm2>
    </elm1>";
```

Recursive comparison:

```
// Just a helper.
private static Tuple<XElement, XElement> Compare(
    string xml1, 
    string xml2, 
    bool compareAttributeValues)
{
    return Compare(
        XElement.Parse(xml1), 
        XElement.Parse(xml2), 
        compareAttributeValues);
}

// Compares XElements recursively
// and returns the two nodes that are different if any.
private static Tuple<XElement, XElement> Compare(
    XElement xElm1,
    XElement xElm2, 
    bool compareAttributeValues)
{
    // Elements are different if they have a different number of children.
    if (xElm1.Elements().Count() != xElm2.Elements().Count())
    {
        return new Tuple<XElement, XElement>(xElm1, xElm2);
    }

    // Enumerate both elements at the same time.
    var elements = Enumerable.Zip(
        xElm1.Elements(), 
        xElm2.Elements(), 
        (x, y) => new Tuple<XElement, XElement>(x, y));
    foreach (var item elements )
    {
        // Elements are equal if they have the same names...
        bool haveSameNames = xElm1.Name.LocalName == xElm2.Name.LocalName;

        // and the same attributes.
        bool haveSameAttributes =
            item.Item1
            // Concatenate and group attributes by their name.
            .Attributes()
            .Concat(item.Item2.Attributes())
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, (key, items) => new
            {
                Name = key,
                Items = items,
                // Attiribute value comparison can be skipped.
                // If enabled compare attribute values.
                // They are equal if the result is only one group.
                HaveSameValues = 
                    compareAttributeValues == false 
                    || items.GroupBy(y => y.Value).Count() == 1,
                Count = items.Count()
            })
            // Each attribute group must contain two items
            // if they are identical (one per element).
            .Where(x => x.Count != 2 || x.HaveSameValues == false)
            .Any() == false;
        if (!haveSameNames || !haveSameAttributes)
        {
            return item;
        }
        else
        {
            // Return the different nodes.
            return Compare(item.Item1, item.Item2, compareAttributeValues);
        }
    }
    // No differences found.
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What if sometimes my elements have sub elements?

Comment: You can call this in a recursive method and compare each element with each other and go deeper if elements are equal until you find a difference.

Comment: Your example was very simple and was about comparing only two elements. You didn't say anything about trees or recursion.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have it in the question, but it could happen, so I really would like to rely on the framework's logic for comparing. I will go with "default locale"'s solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've updated the code for future reference and I've made it recursive.

Answer (score -1):

an issue using the XNode.DeepEquals when there is an empty tags, 
Best way to compare all XML elements from XML documents (this should works even if the XML closing tags are different)

```
    public bool CompareXml()
    {
            var doc = @"
            <ContactPersons>
                <ContactPersonRole>General</ContactPersonRole>
                <Person>
                  <Name>Aravind Kumar Eriventy</Name>
                  <Email/>
                  <Mobile>9052534488</Mobile>
                </Person>
              </ContactPersons>";

            var doc1 = @"
            <ContactPersons>
                <ContactPersonRole>General</ContactPersonRole>
                <Person>
                  <Name>Aravind Kumar Eriventy</Name>
                  <Email></Email>
                  <Mobile>9052534488</Mobile>
                </Person>
              </ContactPersons>";

        return XmlDocCompare(XDocument.Parse(doc), XDocument.Parse(doc1));

    }

    private static bool XmlDocCompare(XDocument doc,XDocument doc1)
    {
        IntroduceClosingBracket(doc.Root);
        IntroduceClosingBracket(doc1.Root);

        return XNode.DeepEquals(doc1, doc);
    }

    private static void IntroduceClosingBracket(XElement element)
    {
        foreach (var descendant in element.DescendantsAndSelf())
        {
            if (descendant.IsEmpty)
            {
                descendant.SetValue(String.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

You could always split the strings at the quotation marks and then compare them.

```
s1Array = s1.Split('\"');
s2Array = s2.Split('\"');

if(s1[0] == s2[0] && s1[1] == s2[1])
    return true;
```

Ignoring empty values is as simple as checking

```
if(s1[1] == String.Empty || s1[1] == null)...
```

Comment: How, exactly, does this help? That only works for an extremely limited set of circumstances.